# append numbers C Programming

Tags: c

If I have the number 88 how would I add 00 to the end of and turn it into 8800? Bitwise shifts is the only way I can think of to do this but it doesn't work. It completely changes the numbers.

Comment: `88 * 100 = 8800`

Comment: What context are you using this in?  as @pzaenger shows, multiplying by 100 is the easiest way to append 00 to a number

Comment: You are describing an operation done on strings. The most direct way it to `strcat()` the zeros to the initial array (make sure the initial array is not read-only and that it has enough space)

Comment: Thank you. The multiply by 100 does what I want :).

Comment: On bitwise shifts: "It completely changes the numbers.", correct. Bitwise shifts multiply and divide by powers of 2 (truncated). "10" is not a single power of 2.

Comment: @pzaenger Thank you that does what I want.

Comment: @MarshallTigerus I get the 88 from reading from a file, then I need to add two 0's to the end, then I use my if statements to modify the two 0's.

Answer (score 2):

Bitwise shifts can only be used to multiply by powers of two, you simply want multiplication. Just run:

```
printf("%d", 88 * 100);
```

to print 8800.

If all you want to do is literally add 00 to the end of numbers you can instead do:

```
printf("%d00", 88);
```

Comment: @self. Sorry, I do not understand well your comment. Are you getting at the fact I have only given a snippet and not a full program? I can flesh it out into a short example if that helps.

Comment: @self. Erhg, sorry, only had about 3 hours sleep last night. Thank you. I am normally not one to make a mistake that dumb

Comment: @chux Good point, fixing now. I just used l out of habit.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do everything with bitwise shift operators alone. Its mathematically impossible to say it straight. But if you still insist you can do something like  (88 << 6) + (88 << 5) + (88 << 2)

As a comment points out your answer can be obtained simply by multiplying your number by hundred.

Comment: Nicely said, I cannot verify the maths in my head but this gives an intuitive demonstration of what shifts actually do.

Answer (score 1):

So, you read from a file, and want to add two zeroes to it.  Two ways I can see to do this: String-wise and Numerically.

String-wise, you can use

```
strcat(inputedText, "00");
```

(or just printf, or possible other solutions)

numerically, you can convert the inputted data from the file to an int, and multiply it by 100.  If you need to print it, Vality's answer shows how to do that.

Comment: thanks, was thinking in Java too much

Answer (score 0):

Live run: http://ideone.com/wiW5Zb

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int64_t calc(int64_t value)
{
    int64_t t = 1;
    while(t < value)
        t *= 10;

    return t;
}

int64_t concatnum(int64_t a, int64_t b)
{
    return (a * calc(b)) + b;
}

int main()
{
    int a = 1000;
    int b = 11;

    int c = concatnum(a, b); //b must be greater 10.

    printf("%d", c);
    return 0;
}
```